# How do I run a repair only within a certain datacenter?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I want to run a repair for specific Cassandra datacenter within a larger cluster. How can I do that `nodetool repair -local -pr` does not seem to work:

```
$ nodetool repair -local -pr
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Primary range repair should be performed on all nodes in the cluster.
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.optionalKSandCFs(NodeCmd.java:1680)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.main(NodeCmd.java:1378)
```

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question with the error message.

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you tunning?

Comment: Datastax Enterprise 4.6.

Comment: Id need the exact version to try to reproduce. 4.6.what?

Comment: Cassandra 2.0.11.83 (or DSE 4.6.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [CASSANDRA-7317](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7317) you should only use -pr when you mean to run repair -pr on ALL the nodes in your cluster (this includes all your data centers). Otherwise, you may end up missing some token ranges in your repair.

The error message you are seeing was introduced in c* 2.0.9 prevent users from running -local and -pr together.

If you just want to repair a local dc, don't use the -pr flag.

To decrease the impact of running repairs check out these options:

#### OpsCenter Repair Service

Takes care of your repairs automatically and spreads them out across your gc_grace period so that you don't 1) have to worry about repairs from an operational perspective and 2) your cassandra ingest isn't affected by an expensive weekly job (repairs are CPU and IO intensive).

#### Repair Service Alternative

If you're not on DSE, the repair service will be grayed out. You can write and manage your own repair service like script. Check out [Stump's github](https://github.com/mstump/cassandra_range_repair) for an example of what this might look like.

**Note**: Keep an eye on this ticket CASSANDRA-6434

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct in all aspects, EXCEPT that Stump's github is no longer maintained by Stump and is only for reducing the effects of broken streams on repairs (longer repairs result in a greater chance of a broken stream, which is an unrecoverable failure).  Use [Gallew's github](https://github.com/BrianGallew/cassandra_range_repair) for a current version.

For an actual repair service, you might try [Limelight Network's github](https://github.com/llnw/cassandra_tools).